# Invoking the HREF attribute of a link with javascript using javascript!

Tags: javascript, click, href, invoke

I never seen this before but you can invoke the HREF attribute of a link using javascript if the HREF contains javascript:;//code......;

On my example below click on both links. they do the same thing even though they have different javascript in the HREF.

for example:

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
            function clickme()
            {
                var link = document.getElementById("clickme");
                eval(link.href);
            }
    </script>
    <a id="clickme" href="javascript:alert('hello');">I will alert hello</a>
    <br />
    <a href="javascript:clickme()">click me</a>
```

I tested this on IE8, Firefox 3.6.8, Safari 5.0.1, and Chrome 6.0.472.55. Is this standardized, so I will not have to worry about this feature being deprecated in the future?

Comment: The answer is: you shouldn't do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to worry about it being deprecated in the future. It's a bad idea *now*.

What's really happening there is this: There's a link using the `javascript:` protocol, which is respected by browsers. It means that everything following the `javascript:` is JavaScript and should be executed by the JS interpreter.

When you retrieve the link's href, you receive it as a string, e.g. "javascript:clickme()". You can use `eval` on strings to execute JavaScript. Now, you'd think that would fail (because of the `javascript:` protocol thing at the front), but it doesn't, because JavaScript has *labels* and that looks like a label when you treat it as JavaScript code.

So it works, but it's a bad idea. It's also disallowed (because of the `eval`) in the new "strict" mode of the latest version of JavaScript, ECMAScript 5th edition.

In general, when we think we need to use `eval` for something, it indicates that there's a problem with our code and that some refactoring is in order. The exceptions to that rule are very edgey edge cases that most of us will never run into. In this case, rather than having the `href` attribute contain the code that we want to execute, it should just *use* the code we want to execute. Your example, for instance, has a `clickMe` function as the only thing being used. Rather than `eval`ing it, we should just call that function directly.

Comment: Good explanation of the label.

Comment: Eval is used a lot in .NET especially the ajax toolkit.

Also, Eval is very necessary in my case because I am trying to execute the click event for the Link Button control. I do not feel the need to strip out the code, bind it to the click event and invoke it.

Comment: @ncaatrackstar: The fact that the .Net toolkit uses `eval` is not an argument that doing so is a good thing. ;-) And it is *not* necessary in your case, it's a choice you're making. Which is fine, it's your choice to make, but it's totally not necessary.

Comment: You are right, T.J(about me having a choice). I can use window.location = link.href, will accomplish my task. Thanks. You mentioned about eval is going to be "disallowed" in ECMAScript 5th edition, where is this mentioned. And if that is true, millions of websites are doomed.

Comment: @Robert: Only in the strict mode, which is something you (the programmer) have to explicitly enable (but does several helpful things if you do). More here: http://ejohn.org/blog/ecmascript-5-strict-mode-json-and-more/

Answer (score 1):

It won't be deprecated but I don't see the use of it.

If you do want to stream line this more do:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            function clickme()
            {
                 clicked();
            }
            function clicked()
            {
                alert("hello");
            }

    </script>
<a id="clickme" href="javascript:clicked();">I will alert hello</a>
<br />
<a href="javascript:clickme()">click me</a>
```

Or better yet do:

```
  <a href="#" onclick="clicked();">Click Me</a>
```

Or even better:

```
<span onclick="clicked();" class="MakeMeLookLIkeLInk">Click Me</a>
```

Anchor controls are mainly used for navigation, and as a good practice to keep it that way. if you have functionality that needs to take place, use a span/div with an onclick. You can use a button as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is whether the line

```
eval(link.href);
```

is valid.

The answer to that is yes, it is. There's no reason you can't evaluate code that's stored in some property, the same way you could evaluate the contents of an input box.

That said, this looks like a VERY bad way to code things. If you're not careful, you could end up in a circular loop. Additionally, code like this will be very hard to maintain.

Comment: Thanks Paul. I didn't think javascript://and some code; was considered code that could be evaluated.

Comment: It's not... // doesn't work right. T.J.'s answer has a good explanation.