# Execute javascript code in a href tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page with several (100+) entries like this:

```
<a href="javascript:removeFromCart(12302, 2);" class="remove">Remove</a>
```

Now I am looking for a jQuery snippet which can be run in the console and helps me to "click" all those "links" and execute the javascript function removeCart() with the respective parameters.

This does not work:

```
$("a[href^='javascript']:contains('Remove')").click()
```

Any ideas?

Comment: $('a.remove').click(); ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery click doesn't work on hyperlink](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053598/jquery-click-doesnt-work-on-hyperlink)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can’t use `.click()` here, because there is no event binding for the anchor. You need to manually execute the contents of the `href` attribute, and that can easilly be done using `eval()`:

```
$('.remove').each(function() {
    eval(this.href);
});
```

Comment: There's no need to use `eval` here.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker what's your proposed solution?

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker "need" - is that a joke? It’s a solution and it works. You shouldn’t downvote based on your personal vendettas against perfectly useable javascript core functions.

Comment: @David: Set `window.location.href` like the duplicate mentions: http://jsfiddle.net/Q9ZTc/2/

Comment: imo setting `window.location` to run JS is way more dirty than `eval`. +1 for a solution that works.

Comment: Nice and elegant! Thanks David!

Comment: [in another question, some expressed an opinion that this is a bad idea.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3688578/invoking-the-href-attribute-of-a-link-with-javascript-using-javascript) I am not a JS dev, just curious whether this is a _right thing to do_.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a new field and pass the parameters there like `<a href="#" data-a="12302" data-b="2" class="remove">Remove</a>`

```
$("a.remove").each(function(){
    var param1 = $(this).data('a');
    var param2 = $(this).data('b');
    removeFromCart(param1, param2);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`.trigger("click")` does not actually perform a user click, but any code binding to the "click" event. You need to set the window location instead:

```
$("a[href^='javascript']:contains('Remove')").each(function() {
  window.location.href = $(this).prop("href");
});
```

Comment: Since we've included a check for the javascript protocol inside the href in our selector we don't need to worry.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('.remove').trigger('click',function(){
       // place your code
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can move the parameters in the javascript function to data attributes first

```
<a href="#" data-param1="20433" data-param1="2" class="remove">Remove</a>
```

then work on the class selector.

```
$("a.remove").each(function() {
  var param1 = $(this).attr('data-param1');
  var param2 = $(this).attr('data-param2');
  removeFromCart(param1, param2);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the only way to trigger the code is actually to execute it.

```
$("a[href^='javascript:removeFromCart']").each(function() {
    eval($(this).attr('href').substr(11));
});
```